# Configuring Geoserver to use a specific postgis geometry column as the default

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geometry

I have a PostGIS table with two geometry columns, both multipolygon but one with SRID 4326, the other 3857. When publishing the table in Geoserver, I realize that Geoserver defaults to using the first geometry column in the list of columns, but I was wondering if there is a way to configure Geoserver to use a specific geometry column?

I’m not talking about configuring the SLD to render using a specific geometry column, ie:

```
<se:PolygonSymbolizer>
<se:Geometry>
<ogc:PropertyName>geom3857</ogc:PropertyName>
</se:Geometry>
…
</se:PolygonSymbolizer>
```

I’m talking about having Geoserver use a specific geometry column as the native SRID and default projection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to deal with this situation is to expose the geometry column you want using a view. Then just point GeoServer at the view rather than the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW parcels_3857 AS 
SELECT "PARCEL_VIEW".geom_3857 as geom
FROM "PARCEL_VIEW";
```

Comment: This certainly seems like a reasonable and logical way to do this, but it seems like more of a workaround of a missing feature of Geoserver than the standard procedure. Thanks for the response.